# Socket.IO always emits to last connected client

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have a problem with Socket.IO (Node.JS).
I try to emit something to a client that makes a request, but Socket.IO answers to the latest connected client.
For example: I connect with my computer to the site, and connect with my laptop after that. Now I make a request with my computer, but my laptop is getting the answer.
My code looks like this:

Server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server, { log: false });
var socket = socket;

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket_) {
    socket = socket_;

    socket.on('dl_me', function (result) {
        downloadTrack(result, result.song_uri);
        if (typeof callback == 'function' ) {
            callback({
                success: success
            });
        }
    });
});

var downloadTrack = function(result, uri) {
    socket.emit('gotodownload', {
        id: generated_number
    });
}
```

Client:

```
var socket = io.connect( window.location.href );
socket.on('gotodownload', function(result) {
    var linktodl = window.location.host + '/getme/' + result.id;
    document.getElementById('dlbutton').innerHTML = '<a href="http://' + linktodl + '">Download!</a>'
});
```

It's not the complete code, but every relevant socket.io part.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the socket object to your `downloadTrack` function:

```
// Add an argument for the socket object.
var downloadTrack = function(socket, result, uri) {
    socket.emit('gotodownload', {
        id: generated_number
    });
}
```

And modify the code inside `dl_me` event to call the function like:

```
socket.on('dl_me', function (result) {

    // Pass the socket to the function.
    downloadTrack(socket, result, result.song_uri);

    // ...
});
```